Process cannot access the file crash in iText7
I recently upgraded my code to iText7 from iTextSharp. Acrobat is crashing sometimes when I try to create a PDF:
Unhandled exception :  The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\AnesthCaseSummary.pdf' because it is being used by another process.
System.IO.IOException
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter..ctor(String filename)
at Anesthesia.FormAnesthesia.ExportToPdf()
at Anesthesia.FormAnesthesia.ToolStripMenuItemCaseSummary_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

To deal with this I added a method to find and kill all the Acrobat related processes:
public void FindAndKillAcrobatProcess () {
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in processes) {
if (p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Acro") || p.ProcessName.StartsWith("RdrCEF") || p.ProcessName.StartsWith("Adobe")) {
try {
p.Kill();
}
catch { }
}
}

}
public void ExportToPdf () {
try {
FindAndKillAcrobatProcess();
}
catch { }
string MyPath = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\AnesthCaseSummary.pdf";
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(MyPath);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
iText.Layout.Document doc = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf);
etc........
}

Which I thought was working but I just got the above crash again yesterday. Is there any way to improve my code to keep this from happening? Is there another non-Adobe process I should be killing to prevent this from happening?
Thanks.
Kill all Adobe related processes before creating PDF
